# Axios.delete error deleting data from database, “Error: Request aborted”

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, handlebars.js

I use Vue 2.3 and mongo,nodejs, express and handlebars , original use handlebars and i can delete

```
  <form class="center"
                  action="/audioannotations/delete/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                  <a
                    onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">
                    <i 
                      class="fa fa-trash-o"
                      aria-hidden="true" 
                      style="color: red;"></i> 
                    Eliminar
                  </a>
                </form>
```

but remplace with vue  and Trying to **delete** data from database  and this is how I am using controller and route for this:
and obtain his error, what happen?

```
Error: Request aborted
    createError webpack:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js?:16
    handleAbort webpack:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js?:73
```

**this value from my id**

```
5fd826c18f741e6eb1ea72c0
```

**this value console.log(url)**

```
/audioannotations/delete/5fd826c18f741e6eb1ea72c0
```

**View**

```
 <a href="" @click="borrarAudioanotacion(item2._id)">Delete </a>
```

**controller**

```
  borrarAudioanotacion(id) {
      var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
      const url = `${currentUrl}/delete/${id}`;
      // /audioannotations/delete/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE
      this.axios.delete(url).then(
        (response) => {
          console.log("si se borro");
          console.log(url);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("no se borro " + "/audioannotations/delete/" + id);
          console.log(url);
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    },
```

**Router**

```
router.delete(
  '/delete/:audioannotation_id',
  ensureAuthenticated,
  ensureColabUser,
  audioannotationsController.deleteAudioannotaion
)
```

Comment: Try `@click.prevent="borrarAudioanotacion(item2._id)"` to stop the page from navigating and cancelling your AJAX requests

Comment: add `@click.prevent="borrarAudioanotacion(item2._id)`  , I now can delete, but show me this message  **Request failed with status code 400**

Answer (score 0):

Add  `return res.status(200).json({"file":"ok"})` in server api